# Trouble finding my error showing the limit of $e^{x^{e^{-x}}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, exponential-function

I have found a way to proof this, but I would really like to know where the error in my initial approach is, since I am only comfortable when I can use different methods. So I don't need a solution to this problem but a correction of my (false) way. The limit is: $$\lim_{x \to \infty}  (e^{x^{e^{-x}}}) = e $$

I tried: $$ a = e^{x^{e^{-x}}}\\ ln(a) = ln (e^{x^{e^{-x}}}) \\ ln(a) = e^{-x}  ln(e^x) \\ e^{ln(a)} = e^{e^{-x}ln(e^x)} \\ a = e^{e^{-x}x}  \\ a = e^{\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{e^x}} \ \ \ (l'hopital) \\ a = e^{\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^x}} \\ a = e^0 = 1$$
I know it's not written down flawlessly, but I hope you get the idea of what I was trying to do..Why is my result 1 and not e?

Comment: Your second to third line of work is incorrect. Pulled out to the front should have been $\ln(a) = x^{e^{-x}}$

Comment: One problem here is that there is no clarity on the exponents; is it $$e^{(x^{e^{-x}})}$$ or $$(e^x)^{e^{-x}}$$?  Since the initial limit has no parentheses, we must assume the former, giving the earlier comment's result.

Comment: @abiessu (e^x)^(e^-x), sorry for that being unclear.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh, I see. Thanks for the input, I'm going to try it with the corrected line right away.

Comment: OP your clarification is wrong. That limit you directed to abiessu converges to $1$, not $e$. The other option neatly converges to $e$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh man, sorry for the confusion. Maybe it is too late to do math problems and I should probably just go to sleep. I will check both limits tomorrow.. sorry again, and thanks for your time and help!

Comment: You’ve correctly computed the limit of $$\left(e^x\right)^{e^{-x}}$$ which is different from $$e^{x^{e^{-x}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We’ll assume we know $$\lim_{y\to\infty}y^{1/y}=1.\tag 1$$

Then note that since $e^x>x$ for any real $x,$ then $$0<e^{-x}<1/x$$ for $x>0.$

But then $$1<x^{e^{-x}}<x^{1/x}$$ for $x>1.$ So by the squeeze theorem and (1), $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{e^{-x}} =1.$$

From this we see:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{x^{e^{-x}}} =e^1=e.$$

---

Your error is that you interpreted the expression as $$\left(e^x\right)^{e^{-x}}$$ which if you let $y=e^x$ is $y^{1/y},$ and gives a limit of $1,$ as you calculated, again from (1).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the limit exists, take two logs or log log of your limit

$$\ln \ln L = \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}\ln x = 0$$

Thus $L=e^{e^0} = e$